# calling a background.js function from webpages

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, postmessage

hi i have a function at background.js

```
function cookielog()
{
chrome.cookies.getAll({},function(c){console.log(c);});
}
```

i want to call this cookielog from any webpage

i have seen this

[sending message to chrome extension from a web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11431337/sending-message-to-chrome-extension-from-a-web-page)

but it didn't work for me, i get this error

```
attempting to use a disconnected port object
```

in my webpage's execute js

```
var customEvent = document.createEvent('Event');
customEvent.initEvent('cookieyolla', true, true);
function fireCustomEvent(data) {
    hiddenDiv = document.getElementById('cookieyolla');
    hiddenDiv.innerText = data;
    hiddenDiv.dispatchEvent(customEvent);
}
fireCustomEvent(5);
```

background.js

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
if (tab.url.indexOf('http') == '0' && changeInfo.status == 'complete') {
    try {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {
            code: 'if(typeof onceworked==\'undefined\'){var onceworked=true;var port=chrome.extension.connect();port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg){if(msg.message==\'cookieyolla\'){setTimeout(function(){alert(\'sik beni\');chrome.cookies.getAll({},cookielog);},msg.values*1000);}});var iDiv=document.createElement(\'div\');iDiv.id=\'cookieyolla\';iDiv.style.display=\'none\';document.getElementsByTagName(\'body\')[0].appendChild(iDiv);document.getElementById(\'cookieyolla\').addEventListener(\'cookieyolla\',function(){port.postMessage({message:\'cookieyolla\',values:document.getElementById(\'cookieyolla\').innerText});});};',
            allFrames: true,
            runAt: 'document_end'
        });
    } catch (e) {
    }
}
```

});

what i am doing wrong?

```
if (typeof onceworked == 'undefined') {
    var onceworked = true;
    var port = chrome.extension.connect();
    port.onMessage.addListener(function (msg) {
        if (msg.message == 'cookieyolla') {
            setTimeout(function () {
                alert('sik beni');
                chrome.cookies.getAll({}, cookielog);
            }, msg.values * 1000);
        }
    });
    var iDiv = document.createElement('div');
    iDiv.id = 'cookieyolla';
    iDiv.style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(iDiv);
    document.getElementById('cookieyolla').addEventListener('cookieyolla', function () {
        port.postMessage({
            message : 'cookieyolla',
            values : document.getElementById('cookieyolla').innerText
        });
    });
};
```

code:"" part as formatted

best regards

Answer (score 0):

@Mustafa, you should read though [long-live connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337672/reason-for-uncaught-error-attempting-to-use-a-disconnected-port-object?rq=1).

> Sometimes it's useful to have a **conversation that lasts longer than a single request and response**. In this case, you can open a long-lived channel from your content script to an extension page , or vice versa, using **runtime.connect** or **tabs.connect**, respectively . The channel can optionally have a name, allowing you to distinguish between different types of connections.

Also, try using [Dev Tools](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging). This will help you pause the action on uncaught errors/exceptions.