# Uncaught Error Attempting to use a disconnected port object in Vue CLI App?

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

I've created a VueCLI App and once it runs on any web browser, the console shows following error when any action performed on a page, like a scroll down or up and click  anywhere on the page,

`Uncaught Error: Attempting to use a disconnected port object
    at w.k.fa (content.js:16)`

any help?

Comment: Possible duplication of
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337672/reason-for-uncaught-error-attempting-to-use-a-disconnected-port-object/6462762

Comment: problem solved, the error comes with chrome extensions. thanks @RóbertKovács

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337672/reason-for-uncaught-error-attempting-to-use-a-disconnected-port-object/6462762) thread says, I disabled some plugins on browser, and re-run it. Then this error didn't rise.